# Requests python not fetching data

Tags: python, python-requests

is there a reason why the requests isn't getting any data? I tried doing it on my VM, and it works normally but when i tested it in my server, it doesn't work at all. I've made sure that the requests library is installed in my environment I and also made sure that it's up-to-date with its version. here is the code that i use.

```
import requests

exist=[]
url = []
cli = ["nike", "duolingo", "duolingoindo"]
for i in cli:
    r = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/"+i+"/")
    try:
        if r.apparent_encoding == 'Windows-1252':
            exist.append(i)
            print('Exist')
            url.append("https://www.instagram.com/"+i+"/")
        else:
            print("Not Exist")
    except:
        print('Not Exist')
```

When I ran this code instead of getting exists, it kept saying that it doesn't exist. I've checked that the account exists. How do I fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the "Not Exist" you are getting isn't coming from the `except`? try running it without the try-except and see if you are getting an exception

Comment: You are ignoring any error in the `try except` clause. I suspect you are getting an error, that and error is happening during the execution. If you let the error bubble up, and look at it, you might get more info into what is happening

Comment: I ran the code myself and the "Not exist"'s came from the else statement

Comment: Maybe you need some specific header? Or it's the matter of network, like the VM has access to the resources, but your hosting provider doesn't?

Comment: @RonSerruya I tried it on the VM, and the try and except line didn't make the request go error, it still manages to pull the data and show that the account exists instead of not exists

Comment: I suspect that the error might possibly come from the Network server-side @Gameplay

Comment: The question is the then where do you serve it from. If it's a cloud provider like AWS, Azure, GCP then there are some ingress/egress rules which you can setup

Comment: @Gameplay i think i need my server to open port 443

Answer (score 1):

The way I found to make sure the Instagram username exists or not is by setting the `sessionid` cookie on HTTP requests. Adding the cookie ensures that the HTTP request will use your Instagram account login session information. Use the BeautifulSoup Selector to be able to validate whether the Instagram username exists or not using the innerHTML of the `title` element.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

exist=[]
url = []
cli = ["nike", "duolingo", "duolingoindo"]
for i in cli:
    r = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/"+i+"/", cookies={"sessionid":"your-session-id"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    title = soup.find('title').text
    if i in title:
        exist.append(i)
        print('Exist')
        url.append("https://www.instagram.com/"+i+"/")
    else:
        print("Not Exist")
```

---

**Without `BeautifulSoup`**

```
import requests

exist=[]
url = []
cli = ["nike", "duolingo", "duolingoindo"]
for i in cli:
    r = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/"+i+"/", cookies={"sessionid":"your-session-id"})
    if r.apparent_encoding == 'Windows-1252':
        exist.append(i)
        print('Exist')
        url.append("https://www.instagram.com/"+i+"/")
    else:
        print("Not Exist")
```

---

**How to get session id:**

1. Log in to your Instagram account via browser.
2. After successful login, perform element inspection and open one of the requests on the `Network` tab.
3. The `sessionid` value can be seen in the `cookie` in the Request Headers.

[image: how-to-get-session-id]

Comment: This doesn't exactly answered my question, but this one works. I'm still really confused on why a normal requests without the help of beautifulsoup works on my VM but it doesn't work on my server

Comment: It's due to strict Instagram API rules. So hard to solve this problem with only a simple request

Comment: Is it not because of the server side? @Jordy

Comment: I think the code is working without `BeautifulSoup` library.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this the print(exist) and print(url) statements are moved outside the loop to show the final lists of existing usernames and URLs.

```
import requests

exist = []
url = []
cli = ["nike", "duolingo", "duolingoindo"]

for i in cli:
    try:
        r = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/" + i + "/")
        if r.apparent_encoding == 'Windows-1252':
            exist.append(i)
            print('Exist')
            url.append("https://www.instagram.com/" + i + "/")
        else:
            print("Not Exist")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print('Error:', e)

print(exist)
print(url)
```

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work at all, my guess is that possibly it's from the network side that's blocking the data from fetching