# Get Post Image Instagram

Tags: node.js, axios, instagram

for years you were able to recover the image of an Instagram post using [https://www.instagram.com/p/{post_slug}/media/?size=l](https://www.instagram.com/p/%7Bpost_slug%7D/media/?size=l)

It was used because the original image had an expiration time, this link always redirects to an active link.

For example: https://www.instagram.com/p/Cr7Ub8ULkzV/media/?size=l

Today I realized that when accessing in anonymous mode (without being authenticated on Instagram) it returns 404.
Does anyone know how to get around this? I already tried to set cookie and user-agent in Axios but the error continues

Another curious fact is that if you follow the example link it also returns 404, but if you go to the URL and press enter the photo appears
By insomnia/postman everything goes well. Looking at the requests I noticed that when you successfully access the photo in the header the "sec-fetch-site" is none, While the site is redirected and the 404 occurs in the header, it remains as cross-site

Comment: You should set `sessionid:your-session-id` on the cookies request. Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75579422/12715723

Comment: @Jordy Did you succeed in the example by setting the sessionid? I tried here and without success.
What I noticed is that entering the link in the browser (even in incognito mode) it opens, but if you open it through another link it returns 404. By Insominia it always works, but by axios it doesn't